# Dynamic Mesh Calculation in Unity is not Indexing Triangles Properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I'm building a game with Unity and I want to generate a map of square tiles and I am using mesh for it, but for some reason my mesh does not render properly. The last column and a half are invisible.

Here are some pictures:

[Shaded view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp157.png)

[Wireframe view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUZhe.png)

And here is the code:

```
void GenerateMesh()
{
    mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    mesh.Clear();

    Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[(Map.WIDTH + 1) * (Map.HEIGHT + 1)];
    int nextIndex = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x <= Map.WIDTH; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= Map.HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            vertices[nextIndex] = new Vector3(x * Square.SIZE, 0, y * Square.SIZE);
            nextIndex++;
        }
    }

    int[] triangles = new int[6 * Map.WIDTH * Map.HEIGHT];
    nextIndex = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < Map.WIDTH; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Map.HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            triangles[nextIndex] = x * Map.HEIGHT + y;
            triangles[nextIndex + 1] = x * Map.HEIGHT + y + 1;
            triangles[nextIndex + 2] = (x + 1) * Map.HEIGHT + y + 1;

            nextIndex += 3;

            triangles[nextIndex] = x * Map.HEIGHT + y;
            triangles[nextIndex + 1] = (x + 1) * Map.HEIGHT + y + 1;
            triangles[nextIndex + 2] = (x + 1) * Map.HEIGHT + y;

            nextIndex += 3;
        }
    }

    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.triangles = triangles;

}
```

Map.WIDTH, Map.HEIGHT and Square.SIZE are constants and their values are 80, 45, 1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Quick thing to check: if you reduce Map.WIDTH by 1 (to 79), do you seem the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first inner loop for y values is using `<=`

```
for (int y = 0; y <= Map.HEIGHT; y++)
```

So your second set of loops should be using `Map.Height + 1` for its index calculations:

```
for (int x = 0; x < Map.WIDTH; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < Map.HEIGHT; y++)
    {
        triangles[nextIndex] = x * (Map.HEIGHT + 1) + y;
        triangles[nextIndex + 1] = x * (Map.HEIGHT + 1) + y + 1;
        triangles[nextIndex + 2] = (x + 1) * (Map.HEIGHT + 1) + y + 1;

        nextIndex += 3;

        triangles[nextIndex] = x * (Map.HEIGHT + 1) + y;
        triangles[nextIndex + 1] = (x + 1) * (Map.HEIGHT + 1) + y + 1;
        triangles[nextIndex + 2] = (x + 1) * (Map.HEIGHT + 1) + y;

        nextIndex += 3;
    }
}
```